# C# method lines program

Tags: c#

I need method of lines, so that when you have method call `Rows (4)`, a method prints four blank lines.

This is my code but it wont work, tell me what is wrong?

```
namespace something
{ 
  class Program 
  { 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      Console.Write("give number: "); 
      int lines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
      line(lines); 
      Console.WriteLine("lines end"); 
      Console.ReadKey(); 
    } 

    private static void line(int lines) 
    { 
       for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++); 
       Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `;` at the end:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++);
                                ^
```

In this case your `Console.WriteLine(" ");` called only once after loop finished. Loop doing nothing.

Comment: Hence why its always best to add function block delimiters { and } even when not needed as this type of error is easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++);  // note the semicolon!
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

The colon is an empty instruction in its own right. So basically your program was executing an empty instruction **n** times (or 'lines' times, actually), and it would write an empty line only ever once afterwards.

Interestingly, the `Possible mistaken empty statement` compiler warning is only displayed when you enwrap the `Console.WriteLine` line in brackets.

Whatever causes that, it seems like a one more good reason to use brackets, even for code blocks consisting of single instructions.

Thus I would recommend:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colon on the end of your for clause is the issue. Your loop isn't doing anything.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check for the user input to be a number, and display an error message if it isn't. The code, like that, will throw an exception if the user inputs something that can't be parsed to an int.

Then there's the semicolon at the end of the for. That's a compiler error which I think you already noticed when trying to run it.

Apart from that, what exactly is not working? Your "line" method is printi a white space for every number, and not a line. If you want to print a blank line, use Environment.NewLine

Comment: `Your "line" method is printi a white space for every number, and not a line.` - you're wrong. `Console.WriteLine` is not the same as `Console.Write`. `WriteLine` automatically inserts a line break at the end of the string. Also, the semicolon does not give a compiler error, just a warning, and not always (as I stated in my answer).

Comment: I don't think anyone uses `Console` very often (other than for homeworks, or perhaps quick "sanity checks") ;)